# how to save output of a function to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, function

I have a function called fslnvols which gives the number of images in a 4D image.

Usage:

```
fslnvols <input>
```

I wanted to save the output of the function to variable A,so I tried:

```
A=fslnvols inputimage
```

and

```
fslnvols inputimage

A=$(fslnvols)
```

but I didn't get the wanted result, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: "*but none of them worked*" what does that mean? `var=$(foo)` will store the stdout of the `foo` command in `$var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use command substitution, `$()`:

```
A=$(fslnvols inputimage)
```

The command whose output you want to store as variable `A`, goes inside `$()` -- `fslnvols inputimage` in this case.